# Button height problem in MSIE 6, 7

Tags: css

Im trying to style a button with this:

```
button.plusone { width: 3.5em; padding: 3px 0 3px 0; text-align: center; }
```

Using the following css reset:

```
button {margin:0;padding:0;}
button {font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-style:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}
button {*font-size:100%;}
```

In Safari and Firefox looks fine, but in Internet Explorer 6 and 7 looks too tall.

Safari, good [saf http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/1954/safay.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/1954/safay.png)

MSIE6, bad [msie http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/8300/75657632.png](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/8300/75657632.png)

Is this a known bug? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having this problem also, and google hasn't yet helped, I hope something can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I decided to do it as a link and display:inline-block

Answer (score 2):

Hai victor,

Here is the fix for your question http://jehiah.cz/archive/an-even-better-ie-button-width-fix

and this 
http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/

or try setting

```
button {
width: auto;
overflow: visible;
line-height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thanks Pandiya, but didn't work. Now it looks bad in Safari also.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the typical box model problem, where IE 6,7 incorrectly calculates height to include the 3px padding you have for top and bottom.  You can fix this using a box model hack such as the one below.

```
button.plusone {height: 20px;  width: 3.5em; padding: 3px 0 3px 0; text-align: center; }
* html button 
{ 
    height: 20px; /* For IE 5.x browsers */
    w\idth: 26px; /* For IE 6,7 browsers */
}
```

More on the well known box model issue and workarounds:
http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=E0989953B6F20B41

Comment: thanks, but is it possible to do it without giving explicit heights? (so the button can grow while the text grows)